# linux - bash - read: Illegal option -n

Tags: linux, shell, script

on Ubuntu , I try to pause a **bash** shell script

```
!#/bin/bash
...
read -n 1 -p"pause"
```

I have seen that syntax everywhere so I don't understand why is it not working

and I get this error

```
./build.sh: 14: read: Illegal option -n
```

what I also don't understand is that in the **read** man, there are no -n -p options

are there 2 different read commands in linux ?

sheers

Comment: `read` needs to be a shell builtin, otherwise it wouldn't work. There are about as many `read` commands in Linux as there are shells.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`read` is a [bash builtin](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html#index-read), that has a `-n` option.

You are likely running `dash` which is a simpler shell, where `read -n` elicits that very error message.

Note that your "shebang" is wrong (`!#` instead of `#!`) so you may not be running your script with `bash` as you expect. In Ubuntu, the default shell (`/usr/bin/sh` or `/bin/sh`) [is a soft link to `dash`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/976485/what-is-the-point-of-sh-being-linked-to-dash#976504).